# Can Kerr-Newman BH with charge Q maintain its charge?

Tags: black-holes

In Kerr-Newman metric it has stationary EM tensor Fab solution, with this solution E*B not equal to zero,and the charged particles can be accelerate along magnetic line. With charged particles pulled into BH, can BH hold the cahrge Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astrophysically realistic black holes are expected to have a very small charge as compared to their mass (in geometrized units).  Wald provides an estimate in *General Relativity* (1984), with $e$ standing for the charge of the black hole and $M$ for its mass:

> It should be noted that, in geometrized units, the charge-to-mass ratio of a proton is $q/m \sim 10^{18}$, and for an electron we have $q/m \sim 10^{21}$. Since the ratio of electromagnetic to gravitational force produced on a test body of charge $q$ and mass $m$ by a body of charge $e$ and mass $M$ is $\sim qe/mM$, it would be very difficult for any astrophysical body to achieve and/or maintain a charge-to-mass ratio of greater than $\sim 10^{-18}$, since a body with a larger charge-to-mass ratio would selectively attract particles of the opposite charge.  Hence, in astrophysically reasonable situations it appears that $e \ll M$, so we may neglect the effects of the electromagnetic field on the spacetime geometry and consider only the Kerr family of black holes [rather than Kerr-Newman—*ed.*].

The Kerr-Newman solution (and Reissner-Nordstrom, which can be thought of as a special case of Kerr-Newman) is still of theoretical interest, but it is not expected to be particularly relevant in the "real world" except in the case $e \approx 0$.